# CMake Export Library Correctly

Tags: cmake

I have a small playground project to practice CMake and it contains a library and a sample app that makes use of the library. Have a look: [Project repo on Github](https://github.com/denvercoder21/lib-lib)

The problem I'm facing now, is that the sample app can't find the headers of the library. This is what I do:

```
cd mymath
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
[100%] Built target mymath
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libmymath.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/my-math
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/my-math/even-odd.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/my-math/even-odd
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mymath/cmake/mymathConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/mymath/cmake/mymathConfig-noconfig.cmake
```

I'll then try to build the sample app:

```
cd ../../project
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
```

The `cmake ..` call works fine, but when callin `make`, I'll get this error message:

```
.../lib-lib/project/src/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: mymath/even-odd.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mymath/even-odd.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

compilation terminated.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the `mymathConfig.cmake` file generated by CMake: [mymathConfig.cmake](https://gist.github.com/denvercoder21/69bc6b69ae905f3a86428271c7d68e1c)

**Solution**

I found the culprit, it wasn't in my CMake files but rather the following.

Instead of:

```
#include <mymath/even-odd>
```

I had to:

```
#include <my-math/even-odd>
```

I was under the assumption, that I need the library name for this, but what was needed is the actual folder structure of the include directory. My bad.

Comment: You need to use `target_include_directories(app PRIVATE /usr/local/include/my-math)` in the CMakeLists.txt that builds your app. You need some way to help CMake find where your header files are located.

Comment: But shouldn't that be ready after `find_package(mymath REQUIRED)` was called? Hard-coding the path there doesn't seem good practice to me.

Comment: Yes, hardcoding is not good. Your `install(TARGETS)` seems to be missing an `INCLUDES DESTINATION` for your `install(EXPORT)`. See the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html?highlight=install#installing-targets) for details. Also, does your my-math.cmake export a `mymath_INCLUDE_DIRS`?

Comment: When building you library. You should add for this library 
a call to target_include_directories(my-math PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include> $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/>)

This way, when linking to the library with target_link_libraries(app my-math)
CMake will get include directories information of my-math through my-math-config.cmake, and will make thoose directories accessible to app.

see (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/target_include_directories.html?highlight=target_include_directories)

Comment: @AmitSingh: I had a look at `mymathConfig.cmake` for `mymath_INCLUDE_DIRS` - Or did you mean another file with `mymath.cmake`? Anyway, I added the link to the `mymathConfig.cmake` to my original post, please take a look.

@Noki: I tried with the call to `target_include_directories(...)`, but it's still the same issue.

Comment: @Noki: I just realized `CMakeLists.txt` already had that call, see: https://github.com/denvercoder21/lib-lib/blob/master/my-math/CMakeLists.txt#L13

Comment: @DenverCoder21 
Do you use find_package macro and 
target_link_libraries when linking to mymath ?

Comment: @Noki: Yes, see https://github.com/denvercoder21/lib-lib/blob/master/project/src/CMakeLists.txt - Also, the errors occurs when calling `make` in my project, CMake runs fine or at least passes without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried, and I don't have cmake near me, but I would try

```
include <even-odd.h>
```

reason being that

```
find_package(mymath)
```

would return `/usr/local/include/my-math` for the search path to the include file.